# Handling FormData in nodejs and angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I have a file upload form in html, After submission i will make user input file as formData and i will trigger the nodejs api from angularjs.

In the nodejs - I want to receive the formData and upload into some external storage. That external storage also  requires input file as formData.

But i can't able to receive the formData as formData in nodejs.

Please anyone suggest the solution.

```
$scope.add = function(file) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    $http.post('/uploadFile', fd, {headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}}).then(function(response) {

       console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
}
```

NodeJS

```
app.post('/uploadFile', function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.body); //Undefined
})
```

HTML

```
<form name="addForm" ng-submit="add(videoFile)">
 <input class="file-upload__input" type="file" file-model="videoFile" required>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please post your `html` code also?

Answer (score 0):

Add scope to your `fd` variable like this,

Change your current declaration of `fd` from,

```
var fd = new FormData();
```

To,

```
$scope.fd = new FormData();
```

And while posting, post it as a scope variable like this,

```
$http.post('/uploadFile', $scope.fd, {headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}}).then(function(response) {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `html` code?

Answer (score 0):

As shown [in this repository](https://bitbucket.org/lucapolverini74/uc74-formdata-file-upload)

To log `req.files`

Server side:

```
const formData = require('express-form-data');
const multipartyOptions = {
        autoFiles: true
      };

// parse a data with connect-multiparty. 
app.use(formData.parse(multipartyOptions));
// clear all empty files (size == 0)
app.use(formData.format());
// change file objects to node stream.Readable 
app.use(formData.stream());
// union body and files
app.use(formData.union())
```

Client side:

```
<input id="i1" type="file">
```

and

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', i1.files[0]);
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', formData, { ... omissis ... })
```